# Weird case: JcomboBox.getSelectedItem() return an object not castable to String

Tags: java, swing

comboBox is my array of String that I used to populate my JComboBox

```
JComboBox chooser = new JComboBox(comboBox);
```

Why when I call this second command it returns to me the toString method of the Object class (In the specific: "`[Ljava.lang.Object;@28f4b2ca`") and not a String?

```
courrentKey = String.valueOf(chooser.getSelectedObjects());
```

Comment: `getSelectedObjects()` returns an `Object[]` , what you see is the `toString()` of this _array_ of Objects. Maybe you meant `courrentKey =  chooser.getSelectedItem()` ?

Comment: [`JComboBox#getSelectedObjects`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#getSelectedObjects()) returns an array of `Object`, as documented.  Note the difference between `getSelectedObjects` and `getSelectedItem`, as they are not the same thing

Comment: Ok guys, thank you very much for the fast answers. The problem was as you said the wrong method. getSelectedItems works perfectly as I wanted. If you want to post the comment like an answer i would like to "solve the question".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getSelectedObjects()` returns an `Object[]` , what you see is the `toString()` of this array of `Object`s.

You probably meant to use `courrentKey = chooser.getSelectedItem()`

Answer (score 0):

Some extra info.
The misunderstanding is perhaps that JComboBox works only with String values.

You can initialize a JComboBox with a String array

```
String[] items = new String[] { "LOL", "YOLO" };
JComboBox combo = new JComboBox(items);
```

But afterwards it is still valid to use the **JComboBox.addItem(item)** method to add an Object.
Where item is any Object -> String, Integer, Double, Float, ...
So this is allowed:

```
Integer extraItem = 69;
combo.addItem(extraItem);
```

This is valid unless you parameterize the type at initialisation and afterwards you can only add String objects.

```
JComboBox<String> combo = new JComboBox<String>(items);
```

---

Because of this behavior the **JComboBox.getSelectedObjects()** method returns an array of Objects -> Object[]

To get the selected item you can do the following

```
Object selectedItem = combo.getSelectedItem();
```

or

```
Object selectedItem = combo.getSelectedObjects()[0];
```

And then use the returned value

```
if (selectedItem == null) {
    return null;
} else {
    return selectedItem.toString().trim();
}
```

Comment: Thank you George!  I saw the parameterization choice but i did not connect: it could have been a great clue to get my mistake.